# not able to fire event (timer)

Tags: c#, events

I have a function in winform that is executed every x time (eg. every 60 minutes).
And then it does some stuff, then I want it to wait some seconds (using a timer) and then execute do some stuff part2.

```
 private void goToFtp(int time)
        { 
            double interval = time* 60 * 1000;
            System.Timers.Timer checkForTime = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
            checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
            checkForTime.Enabled = true;
        }



    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timerDelayWatcher = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

         .......Do some stuff part1

            timerDelayWatcher.Tick += new EventHandler(timerDelayWatcher_Tick); // Everytime timer ticks, timer_Tick will be called
            timerDelayWatcher.Interval = (1000) * (5);              
            timerDelayWatcher.Enabled = true;                       
            timerDelayWatcher.Start();
        }


            private void timerDelayWatcher_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            timerDelayWatcher.Stop();

                .......Do some stuff part2

        }
```

The problem is that the timerDelayWatcher_Tick is not fired...any ideias why?

Comment: Just tested your code. It works for me.... Are you sure it executes the code in "Do some stuff part1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use:

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

But first you need add

```
using System.Threading;
```

or use

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

on 5000 are the time in milliseconds

Sample

```
private void timerDelayWatcher_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        timerDelayWatcher.Stop();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            .......Do some stuff part2

    }
```

Comment: This solves the problem , but I still don´t know why my code doesn´t work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the start method on the system.timers.timer firstly, and I would recommend sticking to one type of timer, and pattern of use, say use the system.timer.timer and do the work you need on elapsed, then restart with and wait for the next elapsed event.

Either that or I would suggest looking at the task library and async flow in .net 4/4.5 and as @Ferri suggests using a Sleep

Answer (score 0):

Take also care on loosing reference to the class containing the timerDelayWatcher member.
If it happens the timer is disposed so no more events...